# Multidimensional array values jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

need some help with a script completely on array that I'm doing

```
    skill = [
        //[ID, "NAME", TMLEVEL, Learn, Mastery, Prerequisite, PrerequisiteLvl],
        //Schoolgirl, Fighter
        [0, "Steel Punch", 0, 0, null, null],
        [1, "Shockwave", 1, 1, 2, null],
        [2, "Bull's Eye", 10, 2, 2, null],
        [3, "Burning Rave", 20, 2, 2, null],
        [4, "Shockvibe", 20, 1, 2, null],
        [5, "Sense Breaker", 20, 1, 2, null],
        [6, "Luck Breaker", 20, 1, 2, null],
        [7, "Pumping Heart", 25, 3, 3, skill[3], 1],
        [8, "Armor Breaker", 30, 2, 2, skill[1], 10],
        [9, "Upper Smash", 40, 2, 2, skill[2], 10],
        [10, "Hyper Beat", 45, 4, 3, [skill[2],skill[3]], [10,10]],
        [11, "Tornado Bomb", 50, 3, 3, skill[8], 1]
    ];
```

I need that inside the array, in certain points, to call th array again to put the array value in there, like i have here.
In theory this works fine, without any error, but when i call the array inside it,it says that it's "undefined".

Any one knows how can i do this without rewrite everything on it? (because i use this in +- 300 code lines).

Comment: How are you calling the array thats inside?

Comment: can you show how you are calling the array?

Comment: Cant you access the inner array like this => skill[9][5]? Would return [2, "Bull's Eye", 10, 2, 2, null]

Comment: it's in there, see at number 11 in the end i call skill[8] to get all the value of the array number 8 to the number 11

Comment: He's trying to access the array while defining it, it's not going to work.

Comment: so is there anyway to do something like this?

Comment: your answer i guess ? try it... and comment... [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long process, I have come up with a solution that will replace all prerequisites, even if they are several levels deep (e.g. skill_3 requires skill_2 which requires skill_1...).

This will require your `skill` variable to be correctly declared (in your question, not all of the skills had 7 variables).

Here is an example of what the variable will look like:

```
var skill = [
    //[ID, "NAME", TMLEVEL, Learn, Mastery, Prerequisite, PrerequisiteLvl],
    [0, "Steel Punch",  0,  0,  0,  null,   null],
    [1, "Shockwave",    1,  1,  2,  null,   null],
    [2, "Bull's Eye",   10, 2,  2,  7,      null],
    [3, "Burning Rave", 20, 2,  2,  null,   null],
    [4, "Shockvibe",    20, 1,  2,  null,   null],
    [5, "Sense Breaker",20, 1,  2,  null,   null],
    [6, "Luck Breaker", 20, 1,  2,  null,   null],
    [7, "Pumping Heart",25, 3,  3,  3,      1],
    [8, "Armor Breaker",30, 2,  2,  7,      10],
    [9, "Upper Smash",  40, 2,  2,  2,      10],
    [10,"Hyper Beat",   45, 4,  3,  [2,3],  [10,10]],
    [11,"Tornado Bomb", 50, 3,  3,  8,      1]
];
```

Now, I thought of a function `setPrerequisites()` that will, for 1 skill, recursively set it's prerequisites:

```
Array.prototype.setPrerequisites = function(){
    if (typeof this[5] === "number")
    {
        this[5]=skill[getPosOfSkill(this[5])];
        this[5].setPrerequisites();
    }
    else if (this[5] instanceof Array)
    {
        if (this[5].isSkill()) this[5].setPrerequisites();
        else
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < this[5].length; i++)
            {
                this[5][i] = skill[getPosOfSkill(this[5][i])];
                this[5][i].setPrerequisites();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function uses `isSkill()` to determine whether an array is a skill, or an array of skill IDs:

```
Array.prototype.isSkill = function(){
    return this.length==7 && typeof this[1]==="string";
}
```

It also uses `getPosOfSkill(id)` to look for the right skill in case your skills were listed in no particular order, or if ID's are missing:

```
function getPosOfSkill(id){
    for(var i=0; i<skill.length; i++) if (skill[i][0]==id) return i;
    return false;
}
```

All you have to do is declare your `skill` variable, and then fill it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < skill.length; i++) skill[i].setPrerequisites();

// if you want to see the results
console.log(skill);
```

### Here is a jsFiddle Demo

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to either rethink your whole approach here (recommended), or set those items to null at first, then rerun the declaration:

```
skill = [
    //[ID, "NAME", TMLEVEL, Learn, Mastery, Prerequisite, PrerequisiteLvl],
    //Schoolgirl, Fighter
    [0, "Steel Punch", 0, 0, null, null],
    [1, "Shockwave", 1, 1, 2, null],
    [2, "Bull's Eye", 10, 2, 2, null],
    [3, "Burning Rave", 20, 2, 2, null],
    [4, "Shockvibe", 20, 1, 2, null],
    [5, "Sense Breaker", 20, 1, 2, null],
    [6, "Luck Breaker", 20, 1, 2, null],
    [7, "Pumping Heart", 25, 3, 3, null, 1],
    [8, "Armor Breaker", 30, 2, 2, null, 10],
    [9, "Upper Smash", 40, 2, 2, null, 10],
    [10, "Hyper Beat", 45, 4, 3, null, null],
    [11, "Tornado Bomb", 50, 3, 3, null, 1]
];

skill = [
    //[ID, "NAME", TMLEVEL, Learn, Mastery, Prerequisite, PrerequisiteLvl],
    //Schoolgirl, Fighter
    [0, "Steel Punch", 0, 0, null, null],
    [1, "Shockwave", 1, 1, 2, null],
    [2, "Bull's Eye", 10, 2, 2, null],
    [3, "Burning Rave", 20, 2, 2, null],
    [4, "Shockvibe", 20, 1, 2, null],
    [5, "Sense Breaker", 20, 1, 2, null],
    [6, "Luck Breaker", 20, 1, 2, null],
    [7, "Pumping Heart", 25, 3, 3, skill[3], 1],
    [8, "Armor Breaker", 30, 2, 2, skill[1], 10],
    [9, "Upper Smash", 40, 2, 2, skill[2], 10],
    [10, "Hyper Beat", 45, 4, 3, [skill[2],skill[3]], [10,10]],
    [11, "Tornado Bomb", 50, 3, 3, skill[8], 1]
];
```

That way, the array elements you are trying to access already exist, now you are just overwriting them.

Comment: but with this instead of 300 code lines i use 600 :-/
it may become slow on slower computers no?

Comment: @Nikato if you want to make it right, you should rethink your whole approach. Here you are copying skills in prerequisites, which is unnecessary, you should just use their ID, that would be muuuuch simpler and it would work. The code Dave gave us here will not work if for example skill #1 is a prerequisite of skill #2 and skill #2 is a prerequisite for skill #3. So you should really avoid that.

Comment: what do you suggest then?
i'm doing like Dave said but instead of 2 times i'm overwriting 3 times the code, and works fine

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a easy way, but still has the problem if it's defined after, but since i only call the values defined before there is no problem for now.

But if anyone knows some way better let me know please.

Here is what i do still using only arrays:

```
    var skill = [];
    skill[0] = [0, "Steel Punch", 0, 0, null, null];
    skill[1] = [1, "Shockwave", 1, 1, 2, null];
    skill[2] = [2, "Bull's Eye", 10, 2, 2, null];
    skill[3] = [3, "Burning Rave", 20, 2, 2, null];
    skill[4] = [4, "Shockvibe", 20, 1, 2, null];
    skill[5] = [5, "Sense Breaker", 20, 1, 2, null];
    skill[6] = [6, "Luck Breaker", 20, 1, 2, null];
    skill[7] = [7, "Pumping Heart", 25, 3, 3, skill[3], 1];
    skill[8] = [8, "Armor Breaker", 30, 2, 2, skill[1], 10];
    skill[9] = [9, "Upper Smash", 40, 2, 2, skill[2], 10];
    skill[10] = [10, "Hyper Beat", 45, 4, 3, [skill[2],skill[3]], [10,10]];
    skill[11] = [11, "Tornado Bomb", 50, 3, 3, skill[8], 1];
```

This way i define them and i'm still using the arrays has i wanted (1 night of sleep makes me think much better :P)